# Parse number and unit in grok

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, grok

I'm trying to parse (in Grok) value+unit, I'm having some issues around it. I have a message that contains a value, ie.

> 52.27us

or another one:

> 23ms

I tried using something as simple as

```
%{NUMBER:value}%{WORD:unit}
```

But it fails. I supposed the solution is simple but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this custom pattern in your grok instead:

```
(?<value>[\d.]+)(?<unit>[\D]+)
```

The first pattern will catch all digits and periods and store the resulting data in the `value` field and the second pattern will catch anything that follows the number and is not a digit.